# How to fix Target on closed Protocol error occuring at WaitForSelector command in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm receiving a "Target on closed Protocol Error" when using the WaitForSelector, a very long String as Selector in Puppeteer, any idea how to fix this. Thanks in advance. This error occurs at the last Wait for selector command btw.

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 800});
try{
await page.goto('https://vorlesungsplan.dhbw-mannheim.de/');
await page.waitFor(500);
await page.waitForSelector("body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > a");
await page.click("body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > a");
await page.waitFor(500);
await page.waitForSelector("body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-c > div > a:nth-child(9)");
await page.click("body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-c > div > a:nth-child(9)");
await page.waitFor(500);
//await page.screenshot({
  //  path: './images/Dhbw.png'
//});
await page.waitForSelector("body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-a > div > ul > li.ui-li.ui-li-divider.ui-btn.ui-bar-b.ui-corner-top.ui-btn-up-undefined");

const element = await page.$('body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-a > div > ul > li.ui-li.ui-li-divider.ui-btn.ui-bar-b.ui-corner-top.ui-btn-up-undefined');
const text = await (await element.getProperty('textContent')).jsonValue();
console.log(text);
await page.close();
 await browser.close();
 process.exit();
 }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
 }

 })();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the class `ui-btn-up-undefined` it wouldn't work with the typical selectors - I'm guessing it has something to do with undefined being in the name. Below works for getting the text out of all of the elements that have that other classes that are similar. I wasn't sure of the exact one you wanted but the principle is the same. I have a long `waitFor` in there that you can remove, shorten, or optimize.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
  var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });
  try {
    await page.goto("https://vorlesungsplan.dhbw-mannheim.de/");
    await page.waitFor(500);
    await page.waitForSelector(
      "body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > a"
    );
    await page.click(
      "body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > a"
    );
    await page.waitFor(500);
    await page.waitForSelector(
      "body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-c > div > a:nth-child(9)"
    );
    await page.click(
      "body > div.ui-page.ui-body-a.ui-page-active > div.ui-content > div > div.ui-block-c > div > a:nth-child(9)"
    );
    await page.waitFor(500);

    // added below
    await page.waitForSelector(
      ".ui-li.ui-li-divider.ui-btn.ui-bar-b.ui-corner-top"
    );
    await page.waitFor(4000);
    const element = await page.$$(
      ".ui-li.ui-li-divider.ui-btn.ui-bar-b.ui-corner-top"
    );
    const arr = await Promise.all(
      element.map(async (i, elem) => {
        const hello = await (await i.getProperty("textContent")).jsonValue();
        return hello;
      })
    );
    console.log(arr);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    browser.close();
  }
})();
```